Can you validate a field using apex in a screen flow?
We have a screen flow for escalating cases. We want a validation for if they select a case that already has an active escalation. My thought is to do a SOQL query for escalations on those cases and if the set is not empty throw an exception. If that's not possible then my recommendation would be to just pre-filter out invalid choices but this could lead to people raising bugs because they can't find the case they want to escalate.

What if you did a get before your first screen to check the escalation and then you can have a decision show a screen that it doesn't meet your criteria and then it sort of stops them.

your question mentions Apex -- not clear why that is necessary

Apex is necessary to check if any of the selected cases have open escalation.

As for showing a screen, that's an option but it's not a great experience for the user to leave the page for an error. It would be better if we just showed the error on screen.

Can you not perform queries using Get Records to look for escalations?
